# Table Adapter Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, tableadapter

I have a large project and have to create many table adapters for this project. Is there any to implement table adapter without data set.

I have created the table adpater like that

```
public BookTableAdapter BookAdapter
{
    get
    {
        if (this._BookTableAdapter == null)
        {
            this._BookTableAdapter = new BookTableAdapter();
            this._BookTableAdapter.Connection = Connection;
        }
        return this._BookTableAdapter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, take a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter adapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();`. (4 overloads.)

Comment: @wazz  I m asking about table adapter. is there any to design table adapter to get auto generated code without dataset designer

Answer (score 0):

You can't implement tableadapters without strongly typed datasets but you can easily create hundreds of tableadapters with a single drag. Highlight multiple items in the Server Explorer and drag them into a dataset:

[image]

Once your tableadapters are in the ds, they're in the namespace, and can be new()'d any time you feel like it. You don't need to set a connection for them (they'll get their own, from the connectionstring in the config file) and you don't really need to have them as class wide variables that might be null; just make one whenever you need it. By having them as class variables you can just instantiate them in the constructor and reuse them if you wish. It feels like you're writing more code than you need to, without a compelling reason; making a new tableadapter and inserting a value to a database is no more onerous than making a new string and writing it to the console